# Command doesn't work when invoked with key binding

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

## (Summary)

I defined a Emacs Lisp function and assign it to the keyboard.
When I invoked the function with keyboard shortcut, it runs but it doesn't work correctly.

## (Detail)

I'm using Emacs on WSL 2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2) with Ubuntu.

- Windows: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348]
- Ubuntu: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Emacs=GNU Emacs 26.3
- X Server=VcXsrv 1.20.8.1

I want to copy and paste from Emacs to Windows and vice versa, but I cannot make it easily.

When you use Emacs, you copy selected string with M-w and paste C-y via Kill Ring.
When you use Windows, you copy selected string with Ctrl+C and paste Ctrl+v via Windows Clipboard.These two spaces are different, so you cannot copy string from Emacs and paste to Windows and vice versa.

As a quick workaround, I defined two functions:

```
  (defun wsl-paste ()
    "copy a string from Windows using powershell Get-Clipboard"
    (interactive)
    (insert (shell-command-to-string "powershell.exe -command 'Get-Clipboard'")))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") 'wsl-paste)

  (defun wsl-copy (start end)
    "copy a string from Emscs using Windows' clip.exe"
    (interactive "r")
    (copy-region-as-kill start end)
    (shell-command-on-region start end "clip.exe"))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c")  'wsl-copy)
```

When I hit `C-c v` in an Emacs buffer, then the function `wsl-paste` will be invoked, and the string in the Windows Clipboard will be inserted in the Emacs buffer safely.

But when I selected some string in an Emacs buffer and hit `C-c c`, the function `wsl-copy` will be invoked, but nothing will be copied in the Windows Clipboard.

The strange thing is that when I enter the command `M-x wsl-copy`, then the function works safely and the selected region will be copied in the Windows Clipboard.

I checked `M-x describe-bindings` and confirmed that `wsl-copy` is binded to `C-c c`.
I inserted `(message "started...")` and  `(message "ended...")` at the start and end of the function for debugging and confirmed both message has been shown in the `*Messages*`  buffer.

How can I invoke `wsl-copy` with `C-c c`?

Comment: This is false: *"you cannot copy string from Emacs and paste to Windows and vice versa."*. See option `select-enable-clipboard`. And see the Emacs manual, node [Clipboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I confirmed ```select-enable-clibboard``` is t and I can copy & paste text between Emacs and other X-Window apps like gedit that runs on WSL-Ubuntu as well.

But unfortunately, it uses the Ubuntu Clipboard and it is the different space from Windows clipboard, so my problrm still persists that I cannot copy text from WSL-Ubuntu-Emacs to Windows-Apps (e.g.,Notebad).

Still I want the answer why my function doesn't work with keyboard shortcut.
Thank you.

Comment: As your debug messages are working, it's clear that you *are* invoking `wsl-copy` with `C-c c` and so the question becomes "why does `(shell-command-on-region start end "clip.exe")` [sometimes?] not have the desired effect?".  I don't know the answer (I don't use Windows) but you should probably reframe your question.